# Is there a way in flutter when the height of a column change to have anchored the bottom of the screen and not the top?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project, and I have one screen where I have a column with multiple widgets init. Some of them are AnimatedContainers and in some occasions their height changes. If the AnimatedContainer whose height change is on the screen, by default the content who is above of this widget stays still and we see a 'push' to the content below it ([Example gif with a similar desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h76Wv.gif)). I want to achieve exact the opposite behaviour. I want to hold still the lower part of my column and move the upper one.

I tried to wrap my column with a SingleChildScrollView and set the reverse parameter in true, but I had exact the some behaviour. I also tried different alignments on my column, but nothing seems to change this behaviour.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the behavior you desired by wrapping the upper widget with **Expanded** and giving the lower widget a fixed height.

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
      )),
      AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: _isBig ? 200 : 100,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ],
  ),
```